# Jekyll/kramdown not formatting scala correctly

Tags: jekyll, kramdown

I am trying to contribute some documentation to an open source project, so I'm trying to locally preview the documentation pages, which are part of a github website. But, my code blocks are not being formatted correctly. I have created a minimal example:

**_config.yml**

```
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  hard_wrap: false
  parse_block_html: true
name: test
```

**default.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>{{ content }}</body>
</html>
```

**auth.md**

````
---
layout: default
---
## Authentication

Some description.

```scala
case class User(id: Long, name: String)
// defined class User
```
````

The resulting output from `jekyll build` is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body><h2 id="authentication">Authentication</h2>

<p>Some description.</p>

<div class="language-scala highlighter-rouge"><span class="k">case</span> <span class="k">class</span> <span class="nc">User</span><span class="o">(</span><span class="n">id</span><span class="k">:</span> <span class="kt">Long</span><span class="o">,</span> <span class="n">name</span><span class="k">:</span> <span class="kt">String</span><span class="o">)</span>
<span class="c1">// defined class User
</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in one long line of unformatted code. On the github site (which you can see here http://http4s.org/docs/0.15/auth.html), the html has `<pre>` and `<code>` elements. Like this:

```
<div class="language-scala highlighter-rouge"><pre class="highlight"><code><span class="k">...
```

Since other people do not have this problem previewing the site locally, and I have the same trouble previewing http://typelevel.org/cats/, I assume it is some local configuration issue of some sort. However, I haven't been able to figure anything out. This is my first time using jekyll/kramdown, so I have no experience to leverage.

I have the `github-pages` gem installed, which has given me `jekyll 3.3.1` and `kramdown 1.11.1`.

Comment: Have you tried with tildes ("~") instead of backticks ("`"). Not sure if it makes a difference, but it is what the kramdown docs show for code blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't help. I guess the real issue is that it seems to work fine on github and for other users locally, but it does not work for me.

Comment: That is weird. It seems like it is parsing the contents of the block as markdown. Perhaps try removing 'parse_block_html: true`?

Comment: Aslo, see the last comment in the link discussion, showing a commit that may render some or all options as unnecessary - perhaps remove all the options or the hard wrap option or seomthing from your `_config` file. Link:https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/211

Comment: You probably know this, but since your new to jekyll I'll say it anyway: You have to restart the server everytime you change the `_config` file. Sorry if I am stating the obvious.

Comment: I figured it out after digging through Github documentation. It was actually a version issue. There is a Gemfile and Gemfile.lock file in the repository. For one, they weren't being copied by the build process to the directory where the site was run from. And, I needed to install the bundler gem to install the dependencies with `bundle install`. And then run the site with `bundle exec jekyll serve`.  This differs from the instructions on the repo's website.

Comment: Great. You should put that in as the answer for others who may see this, and perhaps also note it on the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it can help others out:

I figured it out after digging through Github documentation. It was actually a version and installed gems issue. There is a Gemfile and Gemfile.lock file in the repository. For one, they weren't being copied by the build process to the directory where the site was run from. And, I needed to install the `bundler` gem to install the dependencies with `bundle install`. And then run the site with `bundle exec jekyll serve`. This differs from the instructions on the repo's website.